# If $\mu_i \xrightarrow{w} \mu \Rightarrow \int_X f d\mu_i \to \int_X f d\mu$ for all convergent sequences, does it imply $f$ is continuous?

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $\mu, \mu_i $ be Borel probability measures on $X$ for $i \in \Bbb N$.

If for all weakly convergent sequences $\mu_i \xrightarrow{w} \mu$ in $\Delta(X)$ we have $\int_X f d\mu_i \to \int_X f d\mu$, is it necessarily the case that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: There's a pretty trivial counter example where you take a sequence of identical measures ?

Comment: @Evan, I'm not sure I understand your comment. I mean for all weakly convergent sequences, not a particular convergent sequence. I have to omit the "for all" part in title, because it makes the title exceed 150 charaters.

Comment: ohhhhh of course , definitely missed that part, in that case maybe you can just consider sliding point measures as examples

Comment: Let $x \in X$ be a non-isolated point. For any sequence $x_n \to x$, you have $\delta_{x_n} \xrightarrow{w} \delta_x$, so you have $f(x_n) \to f(x)$, hence $f$ is sequentially continuous in $x$, hence it'd continuous in $x$. It's trivially continuous in all isolated points.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Thank you. I got it. Please consider making your comment into an answer.

Comment: It's @Evan's idea from his second comment. Maybe he wants to make it an answer? (If not, I will be happy to make it one.)

Comment: @DanielFischer  nah, go ahead, you have the details :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x \in X$ arbitrary. For every sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $X$ converging to $x$, we have

$$\delta_{x_n} \xrightarrow{w} \delta_x,$$

where $\delta_y$ is the point mass in $y$. The assumption now implies that

$$f(x_n) = \int_X f d\delta_{x_n} \to \int_X f d\delta_x = f(x),$$

and that means $f$ is sequentially continuous in $x$. $x$ was arbitrary, so $f$ is sequentially continuous. For metric spaces, sequential continuity is equivalent to continuity, hence $f$ is continuous.